# Javascript, question about inputs, buttons and more

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, onclick

i im learling how to do code. i got this code but a have problems conecting the fuction parameter whit my input / input.value.
I wish to do it whit that level of learning i mean, i know i cant use "getElementById" and another tools but i wish to know if i can do it in that level
(i im doing a bootcamp and the video they gave us only have that way to teach us)

```
<input>
<button>Encriptar</button>
```

---

```
<script>

var input = document.querySelector("input");
var inputValor = input.value;
```

---

```
function encriptar(palabra){
    var mensajeEncriptado = "";
    for (var i = 0; i< palabra.length; i++) {
        console.log(palabra[i]);
        if (palabra[i] == "a" ){
            mensajeEncriptado += "ai";
        } 
        if (palabra[i] == "e" ){
            mensajeEncriptado += "enter";
        }
        if (palabra[i] == "i" ){
            mensajeEncriptado += "imes";
        }
        if (palabra[i] == "o" ){
            mensajeEncriptado += "ober";
        }
        if (palabra[i] == "u" ){
            mensajeEncriptado += "utaf";
        }
        else {
            mensajeEncriptado += palabra[i];
        }
                      
        }
    return mensajeEncriptado;

    }
```

---

```
 //document.write(encriptar("Hello world"));
 var button = document.querySelector("button");
 button.onclick = encriptar(input.value);
```

---

```
 Someone can help me?
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is the answer you want:

```js
function encriptar(palabra){
    var mensajeEncriptado = "";
    for (var i = 0; i< palabra.length; i++) {
        console.log(palabra[i]);
        if (palabra[i] == "a" ){
            mensajeEncriptado += "ai";
        } else if (palabra[i] == "e" ){
            mensajeEncriptado += "enter";
        } else if (palabra[i] == "i" ){
            mensajeEncriptado += "imes";
        } else if (palabra[i] == "o" ){
            mensajeEncriptado += "ober";
        } else if (palabra[i] == "u" ){
            mensajeEncriptado += "utaf";
        } else {
            mensajeEncriptado += palabra[i];
        }
        // case 'if - if - else' .. -> required 'continue'
        //      -> if () {
        //           // do something;
        //           continue;
        //         } ...
        // So, I recommend using it like : 'if - else if - else'
    } //end of for loop
    return mensajeEncriptado;
}
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var div = document.querySelector("div");

button.onclick = function() {
   var encrypted = encriptar(input.value);
   div.innerHTML = encrypted;
}
```

```html
<input type='text'>
<button>Encriptar</button>
<div>init</div>
```

function 'encriptar' returns string data,
but button.onclick needs function object.